# How do I attach an mp3 to MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, text, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have multiple mp3 files in my project. I would like to know how I can access this file (file path) and attach it to the text message I will be sending out.

Does anybody know how to do this? Please provide some code if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFMessageComposeViewController has a few handy methods for you:

[`func addAttachmentURL(_ attachmentURL: NSURL,
withAlternateFilename alternateFilename: String?) -> Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMessageComposeViewController/addAttachmentURL:withAlternateFilename:)

and

[`func addAttachmentData(_ attachmentData: NSData,typeIdentifier uti: String, filename filename: String) -> Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMessageComposeViewController/addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename:)

You'd probably want to do something like:

```
let pFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:pSongPath];
do {
   let pData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: pFileUrl, options: NSDataReadingOptions())
   pMailComposer.addAttachmentData(pData, mimeType:"audio/mpeg" fileName:@"song.mp3")
} catch let error as NSError {
   print("error while trying to load data - \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

(I didn't run this through a compiler so I might be off an optional or two)

Comment: How would I add my mp3 file to this code? Sorry I am kinda new at this! Thanks!

Comment: I tried doing this but it said my file could not be found?  pSongPath would be where i put my file name right? So if i had an mp3 called -- iloveStack.mp3 it would go there?

Comment: the file URL would be the path to your file.  Where do you keep your file?  Within your app bundle or somewhere else?